# Glade: glib GError when trying to use object attributes

Tags: lubuntu, python, lxde, glade, pygi

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 but with the lubuntu desktop (LXDE) installed manually. I've designed my Python application's UI using Glade. Everything is working fine as long as I don't use attributes (`<attribute>`) in the XML file; when I do, I get the following upon a call to `add_from_file`:

`gi._glib.GError: <input>:18:41 <attribute> requires attribute "value"`

Line 18 is simply the first occurrence of the `<attribute>` tag in the file and looks like this: `<attribute name="weight">bold</attribute>`.

My Python version is `3.4.3`.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you have to add an attribute named `value`.

```
<attribute name="weight" value="bold" />
```

In your definition

```
<attribute name="weight">bold</attribute>
```

is only one attribute with the name `name`. The text between the opening and closing tags isn't an attribute. The tag name `attribute` has nothing to do with the needed attribute of a tag.

---

The structure of a valid XML file is defined in a DTD file, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XML Catalogs V1.0//EN" "file:///usr/share/xml/schema/xml-core/catalog.dtd">
```

In this definition, among others, the necessary attributes for tags are defined. If an XML file does not meet these definitions, then it is not valid. 
In this particular case it could be a bug in Glade (generates non-valid XML) or you have not been validated in advance the XML document.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. This means that Glade seems to be generating erroneous XML code; should I file a bug report?

Comment: Not sure, updated my anwser.